# How to access variable inside event handler function that is inside the main function (without using window)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, variables, bootstrap-4

Using JQuery library, how do I access the `username` and `listStatus` variables both inside event-handlers? I saw in past Stackoverflow posts that you can use `window.[variable name]` but it's bad practice to use this.

```
$(function() {
  $("#search").on("click", function() {
    var username = $("#name").val();
  });
  $(".dropdown-menu a").on("click", function() {     
    $("button.dropdown-toggle").text($(this).text());
    var userSelection = $("button.dropdown-toggle").text();
  });

  var api = `https://api.jikan.moe/v3/user/${username}/animelist/${userSelection}`;
    fetch(api)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log("Success!", data));
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to move the variables to a shared parent scope in order for all the callbacks and functions to access the same value. I would propose something similar to the following:

```js
$(function() {
  let username = null;
  let userSelection = null;
  $("#search").on("click", function() {
    username = $("#name").val();
    tryApiCall();
  });
  $(".dropdown-menu a").on("click", function() {
    $("button.dropdown-toggle").text($(this).text());
    userSelection = $("button.dropdown-toggle").text();
    tryApiCall();
  });

  function tryApiCall() {
    if (username !== null && userSelection !== null) {
      var api = `https://api.jikan.moe/v3/user/${username}/animelist/${userSelection}`;
      fetch(api)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log("Success!", data));
    }
  }
});
```

In this case, you have function `tryApiCall` that gets called in each event handler callback and it only makes an API call if the value of `username` and `userSelection` is present (since you need both values to form the API URL.

Comment: I'm not getting the returning JSON object that's supposed to be returned in console.log(), nothing returns in console tab

Comment: If you check you check the `network` tab in you browser, do you see the API call being made to the correct URL?

Comment: No, [I don't see the API call being made in Network tab.](https://i.imgur.com/syGGAqt.png)

Comment: I'd start adding `console.log` statements and checking if `tryApiCall` gets called and what the values are of `username` and `userSelection`.

Comment: Oh I see something in the console tab. It shows this:
https://i.imgur.com/zU5bRvw.png

Also, it looks like the tryAPICall does not get called for some reason...

Comment: this sucks, im still getting the [same error](https://i.imgur.com/zU5bRvw.png) and haven't found a solution.

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the attempted network request in the network tab of your browser devtools?

Comment: So can somebody help me? I'm getting error saying `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`